# "use of unresolved identifier JSON" when reading data in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase

I'm trying to read data from my firebase JSON and return the topic, content, and date created onto a different page.

This is in my override viewDidLoad function in the table view controller where I'm trying to read the data and return to.

I'm getting an error that says "use of unresolved identifier JSON"

```
let jsonDictionary = JSON(questions: Data)
                let contents = jsonDictionary["content"].array
                for content in contents {
                    var question: [Question] = []
                    question.append(Item(content: item["content"], topic: item["topic"]))
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a framework for handling JSON? Swift doesn't have a value type called `JSON`

Comment: I don't. Do I need one? Sorry I'm pretty new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have to import SwiftyJSON module in your file.

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON